# Get column name of a bit column where value is true

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to create a select query that would return the name of a bit  column if value is TRUE or 1. The only way I could do it is if I added an additional column "Day" and had description of the day reflect the column name to which an available ticket is available.

How can I do this?

```
<cfquery name="getTickets" datasource="test">
SELECT * from tickets
ORDER BY ticketID ASC
</cfquery>
```

Tickets Table (Workaround):

```
ticketID  Monday Tuesday Wednesday Price  Day

1         1      0       0         42.00  Monday
2         0      1       0         42.00  Tuesday
3         0      0       1         42.00  wednesday
4         1      1       1         75.00  All three days
```

Tickets Table (What I would like to use):

```
ticketID  Monday Tuesday Wednesday Price

1         1      0       0         42.00
2         0      1       0         42.00
3         0      0       1         42.00
4         1      1       1         75.00
```

Comment: If your looking to do this service side, consider writing a function, passing over monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, etc... to the function.  In your function, define a string variables, and then append the "true" field names to the string and return it.  You didnt define if you were doing this in mysql, microsoft sql, etc...  You could also do the same thing in coldfusion when outputing your display.

Comment: A name my friends use for me, but not one I was given at birth. Does that satisfy your question? :-)

Comment: Opps. I think someone deleted their comment to a question they asked. @ Steve, I'm new to this and have no clue where to start.

Comment: Is there any guarantee that one row will only have a 1 in one of the day columns? If so, which I think is true, your table structure is wrong.

Comment: @Hardode, no this would be subject to change. So yes, my table structure for the workaround is wrong.

Comment: It is often easier to manipulate data when it is stored in rows, not columns. ie **Table** `Tickets` **Columns:** `TicketID`, `DayOfWeek` (number), `Price`. Any reason such a structure would not work for you?

Comment: @Leigh, this would be subject to change, for example I might choose to   sell out of the Tickets on a given day etc. For the workaround I did as you advised, however the table structure is not sound.

Comment: Not sure why that would make a difference. You can design the front end to do whatever you need. But the database tables should be structured for efficiency and access by the db engine. That is not always going match what the front end looks like (and often does not). (That said, I do not know much about your application. So that is just a general comment)

Comment: This was a database that was provided by my tutor, so no amendments can be done. :-)

Comment: Oh .. that explains a lot. Instructors sometimes do things in a classroom you would not do in real life (as a learning exercise).  Though you might want to mention this is homework up front, so people offer hints rather than writing the query for you ;-).

Comment: It's the learning process that counts! It's a practical not homework. :-P

Comment: *It's the learning process that counts* Good to see someone that is interested in learning :) I am always amazed at how many people are not. Personally I would rather understand the "why", then I can fix it all myself ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I would strongly suggest you do this in the presentation layer, i.e. client end. However, here's a possibility.**

Sample data

```
create table Tickets(ticketID int, Monday bit, Tuesday bit, Wednesday bit, Price money);
insert into Tickets values (1, 1, 0, 0, 42.00);
insert into Tickets values (2, 0, 1, 0, 42.00);
insert into Tickets values (3, 0, 0, 1, 42.00);
insert into Tickets values (4, 1, 1, 1, 75.00);
insert into Tickets values (5, 0, 0, 0, 15.00);
```

A possible query

```
select *,
       STUFF(
       case when Monday=1 then ',Monday' else '' end
     + case when Tuesday=1 then ',Tuesday' else '' end
     + case when Wednesday=1 then ',Wednesday' else '' end, 1,1,'')
from Tickets;
```

To prettify the edge cases ("all three days" and "none"), you can use a CASE statement

```
select *,
       CASE WHEN Monday=1and Tuesday=1and Wednesday=1
            THEN 'All three days'
            WHEN Monday=0and Tuesday=0and Wednesday=0
            THEN 'None'
            ELSE
       STUFF(
       case when Monday=1 then ',Monday' else '' end
     + case when Tuesday=1 then ',Tuesday' else '' end
     + case when Wednesday=1 then ',Wednesday' else '' end, 1,1,'')
            END WhichDays
from Tickets;
```

Comment: Thank you Richard, it works for what I need. How can I return the name of the bit column, so that when a customer views the tickets, they would see the day rather than a 1?

Comment: Please ignore, I saved the document to wrong directory. Works like a charm. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try UNPIVOT

```
;with cte as 
(
  SELECT * FROM 
  ( 
    SELECT * FROM tickets 
  ) v
  UNPIVOT
  ( 
    Available FOR Days IN (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday) 
  ) up
  where Available = 1
)

SELECT ticketid, price, available,
stuff((
    SELECT ', ' + Days
    FROM cte as t1
    where t1.ticketId = t2.TicketId
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, '')
from cte t2
group by ticketid, price, available;
```

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/243a7/5)

Comment: Thank you rs., I think this would be too advanced for my skills. :-)